# Dynamically build angular page via rest config

Tags: angular, typescript

I am building a login page with angular 6. The login should be configurable, either standard login with username and password or single sign-on. On the server side exists a rest interface which provides the config.

The page should show a different element regarding SSO or standard login is selected. Therefore I have a simple ngIf element in my HTML component.

```html
<mat-card class="center">
  <mat-card-content>
    <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center" *ngIf="ssoEnabled; then ssoLogin; else devLogin"></div>
  </mat-card-content>

</mat-card>

<ng-template #ssoLogin>
  <a href="someLink" fxFlex mat-raised-button color="primary">LOGIN-SSO</a>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #devLogin>
  <button fxFlex mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="login()">LOGIN</button>
</ng-template>
```

The 'ssoEnabled' variable gets initialized in the component.class via ngOnInit() method:

```js
export class LoginComponent extends BaseComponent {
  public ssoEnabled: boolean;

  //constructor and other content

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.http.get('/config/sso/enabled').subscribe(value => this.ssoEnabled = Boolean(value));
  }
}
```

My problem is now when the page is rendered the variable 'ssoEnabled' is always undefined, and my ngIf is useless. I think the page is rendered before the http call returns. I have tried several things in my ngOnInit function like pipes or async/await pattern, but the variable always stays undefined.

Has someone a solution for this? Maybe there also exists a better solution for my use case?

Comment: set the default value to ssoEnabled variable. and show loader until you get response from server when you get response from server. then show appropriate View and hide the loader

Comment: How can I show load until I get a response?

Comment: use this library https://github.com/kuuurt13/ng-block-ui#readme   i used this in many project,

Answer (score 0):

Its because subscribe is async function. You render page before you get answer from rest.
You can define ssoEnabled in class by this:

```
public ssoEnabled = false;
```

You must select what is default behavior false or true and use it!
Good luck!

Comment: Do I always have the default behavior then?

Comment: Yes, behavior on page load. What do you want to see first off all?

Comment: I want to see first what is configured on the server.

Comment: This default value will be before server response, after you get response from server you will see what is configured on the server.